# Creating Chrome extension which will highlight specific pre defined word on the website.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm getting error on the below code. I'm getting Iteration error and I'm new to java script. The code just need to highlight the word cart on the website.

```
  Manifest File
  {
"manifest_version":2,
"name":"mytry2",
"version":"0.001",
"content_scripts":[
  {
"matches":[
"<all_urls>"
],
"js":["content.js"]
 }
 ],
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"icon96.png"
  }
  }

 **Content File**
 console.log("chrome extension running");
 var p= "cart"
 var match= document.body.textContent.match(p);
 match.style['background-color']='#FF00FF';
 }
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? Perhaps you should check if `match` is null or undefined before setting its `style`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var p= "cart"
```

There is no ending ";". What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Try wrapping your code in window.onload: 

 `console.log("chrome extension running");
 window.onload = function(){ 
   var p = "cart";
   var match = document.body.textContent.match(p);
   match.style['background-color'] = '#FF00FF';
};`

Comment: Please make sure to eventually update your answer with a complete solution based on OP's comments, otherwise you may get downvotes and flags.